# How install curses-1.06 module in termux

Tags: perl, termux, termux-linux

The cpan command enters module exploration and installation mode.
`>i/Modulo/` informs the modules and their author in the database.
When I say `>i/Curses/` several curses appear but not what I need.
I'm trying to add Curses-1.06 from William Setzer (WPS).
Informing `cpan> i /wps/` shows me the author but not its module. AND...
`cpan> i /WPS/Curses-1.06/`
`No objects found of any type for argument /WPS/Curses-1.06`
I managed to download by
`cpan> install WPS/Curses-1.06.tar.gz`
`Saving to:` `'/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.cpan/sources/authors/id/W/WP/WPS/CHECKSUMS.tmp6759'`
And then fails in perl Makefile.PL guess_cfg...

```
Configuring W/WP/WPS/Curses-1.06.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
FATAL: internal error: guess_cfg is bad
Warning: No success on
command[/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
WPS/Curses-1.06.tar.gz
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/perl
Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
WPS/Curses-1.06.tar.gz
: writemakefile NO '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 65280
```

I opened the Makefile.PL file and I'm trying to add an Android as I don't see one. And I don't know if I'm doing it right.
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.imgur.com/Sb3gn0n.jpg)

```
Notes for Solaris:
# In 2.3, it was reported that to make the module compile correctly
# with gcc, you must add `-DSYSV=1' to $inc. This will disable the
# reset memcpy to bcopy which is present in /usr/include/curses.h.
# [Courtesy of Dave Blaszyk <dvb@ycc.Kodak.COM>]
#
# $inc also contained "-I/usr/include", but this seems to cause a huge
# too many problems for gcc in perl5.002 so i removed it by default.
# I tested Curses-a9 with perl5.002 and gcc263 and Sun's unbundled
# cc on Solaris 2.4 with $inc empty and no problems, but your
# mileage may vary.
#
# If you are having problems compiling on Solaris, try several
# combinations of "-I/usr/include" and "-DSYSV=1" in $inc to see if
# it fixes things.
```

Comment: Hi I tried to install termux on my android phone. Then ran `pkg install perl` and then  downloaded https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/G/GI/GIRAFFED/Curses-1.44.tar.gz with curl.  Then ran `perl Makefile.PL`. But I think it is missing the ncurses c libraries and headers. How did you install those? Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Bz8jZVI

Comment: *"But I think it is missing the ncurses c libraries and headers. How did you install those?"* I found that you can install those with `pkg install ncurses`. The header files will then end up in `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include` and the libraries in `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib`

Comment: If I export those paths in the previous comment to the environment variables `CURSES_CFLAGS` and `CURSES_LDFLAGS` and rerun `perl Makefile.PL` I get another error: "I'm sorry I couldn't find a hints file that was configured for your OS", see this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/u3m02gg

Comment: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/US30Jmu.jpg) First open cpan and tried to install giraffes 1.44 but da fuction not enable like yours @HåkonHægland . I inform `perl Makefile.PL`
That tells me prerequisites curses-1.06 not found
Then I do `cpan>install WPS/Curses-1.06.tar.gz` and I get on installation `FATAL: internal error: guess_cfg.`
@ikegami `perl -le'print $^O'`
android

Comment: @ikegami *"Might suffice to copy c-linux.ncurses.h"* : Indeed! I just did `cd hints; cp c-linux.ncurses.h c-android.h; cd ..; perl Makefile.PL` and it worked, see screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/GnxIJIx

Comment: After running `perl Makefile.PL` the next problem is to run `make`, and I needed to install `make` with `pkg install make` first. Then running `make` produced an error due to missing c compiler, see screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/oFG487Z

Comment: @ikegami because I'm trying to use another Term::Animation module that depends on curses. and when I do cpanm installdeps . it returns failed installing dependencies module curses.
 And then perl Makefile.PL says prerequisite Curses-1.06

Comment: *"Then running make produced an error due to missing c compiler"* The c compiler can be installed with `pkg install clang`, and then `make` runs successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that you will need to install the ncurses C library before you can install (any version of) this module since it's merely an interface to that C library.

This can be done as follows:

```bash
pkg install ncurses
```

---

Secondly, you don't need version 1.06 specifically.

You're trying to install WPS/Curses-1.06.tar.gz. This version dates back to 2001, which is ancient.

Thankfully, you don't need that version specifically. That is the *minimum* version you need. We will focus on installing the latest version, 1.44.

---

Finally, time to install the module.

While the installation process has become less platform-dependent since 1.06, there's still some platform-dependent aspects in the installer.

Unfortunately, the latest version at this time does not support termux, but it's not hard to add the support manually.

First, obtain the distribution.

```bash
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/G/GI/GIRAFFED/Curses-1.44.tar.gz
tar xzf Curses-1.44.tar.gz
cd Curses-1.44
```

Secondly, add support for your OS.

```bash
cp -i hints/c-linux.ncurses.h hints/c-android.h
```

Third, we need to tell the installer where to find the ncurses C library since the installer doesn't find them.

```bash
export CURSES_CFLAGS="-I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include"
export CURSES_LDFLAGS="-L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -lncurses"
```

Finally, complete the installation.

```bash
perl Makefile.PL && make test && make install
```

Comment: Thanks to the help of Håkon Hægland.

Comment: Great write-up, I added a ticket for this also: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=148282